# NPM watchers with forloop

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, babeljs

I want to create a Gulp watcher for every template i create for my project.
The templates are located in my **templates** folder.

I'm using the following code to create my templates:

```
let javascriptTemplates = {
  0: { folder: 'template-1' },
  1: { folder: 'template-2' },
};
```

And the following to create the watchers:

```
gulp.task('start', function () {
   for(let i = 0; i < javascriptTemplates .length; i++) {
     let folder                   = javascriptTemplates[i]['folder'];
     let templateDirectory        = `${javascriptTemplateDirectory}/${folder}`;
     let templateWatcherDirectory = `${templateDirectory}/**/*.js`;

     gulp.watch([templateWatcherDirectory], formatJavascriptFiles(templateWatcherDirectory, folder));
   }
});
```

Is this possible at all with Gulp watchers?
I'm struggling to make it work but can't get it right.
The watcher starts and the **formatJavascriptFiles** function works just fine.
When i save any javascript file the watcher wont start and no files will be minified.

If someone know if this is possible and how i can fix my issue.

Comment: It looks like `javascriptTemplates` is a plain object, not an `Array`. It doesn't have `length` property. So your loop body never runs. Either make it an array or use `Object.keys()` to get keys to loop over.

Comment: Found it. You can't send params with the function of a watcher:

gulp.watch([templateWatcherDirectory], formatJavascriptFiles(HERE));